# Problem with matching date-time fields using MongoDB Spring Data Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Just want to do a MatchOperation on date in long format (date in seconds) in MongoDB
The fromDate and toDate Variables are with data type as long.
It's divided with 1000 to get the data in seconds format and not in milliseconds.

> long fromDate =  new Date().getTime()/1000;

The datetime field format is in mongo Document

> "datetime" : NumberInt(1595745447),

```
MatchOperation matchDate = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("datetime")
                .gte(fromDate)
                .lte(toDate));
```

the aggregation formed using this is

```
db.some_collection.aggregate([{ "$match" : { "datetime" : { "$gte" : { "$numberLong" : "1595356200"}, "$lte" : { "$numberLong" : "1595375999"}}}}])
```

But its not working. It's giving 0 results.
But when the same is just modified (as shown bellow) a bit manually by jus removing

> "$numberLong"

it's giving results and Filters as expected.

```
db.some_collection.aggregate([{ "$match" : { "datetime" : { "$gte" :1595356200, "$lte" : 1595375999}}}])
```

Can any one help me out with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the type of `fromDate` and `toDate`?

Comment: Is the `datetime` document field also in seconds also? How is it defined in the collection's document. Please post a sample document showing the field.  Also, post the variable definitions of `fromDate` and `toDate`.

Comment: Hi @prasad i have updated the question. and YES the datetime document field is in seconds.

Comment: Your aggregation match operation works fine as it is. I tried using spring-data-mongodb v2.3 and MongoDB v4.2.

Comment: @vipinMakde please feel free to post an answer if you solved the issue. It will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error. NumberLong is a function not an operator.

[Refer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#numberlong)

Change

```
   { "$numberLong" : "1595356200"},
```

To

```
  NumberLong("1595356200")
```

Comment: Hi @gibbs, it's not me who is doing that but it''s happening from java code i guess.
By writting simple MatchOperation java is giving that syntax

Comment: OK. Are from and to dates of type Date? And how did you get that aggregate query from Java?

Comment: No they are long format (Date in seconds not milliseconds) 

MatchOperation matchDate = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("datetime") .gte(fromDate). lte(toDate));